# Create and connect locations for a game

Tags: java, object

I want to make a text adventure game as a school project and I was wondering how it would be possible to **create** and **connect** game locations in which the story takes place.

I thought of making a super class `Location` with variables like `name` and a two-dimensional array like

```
int[][] locnow = new int[20][20];
```

for the location position itself (north, west, east, south point).

My main questions are

1. Is it a good way to realise something like this in this way, or is something different better?
2. How can I load locations like "Button Click -> go east" and the location one to the east is loaded?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Very seldom is needed a 4-dim array. I think this is not one of those cases.

Comment: I think you are imagining something wrong. Very inprobably you need 4D array.

Comment: I think you're mad going with a 4 dimensional array! I would stick to 2 dimensions so you have a 20x20 grid then if you want to `goEast()` you would increment the position of the array like `pos[0][0] -> pos[0][1]` - So you move east by one (I'm using pseudo code)

Comment: Why exactly do you want to create a four-dimensional array? Think of it as a matrix (I presume you want to create a grid or something), which has two dimensions: (x, y). If you move east, increment the x value; if you move west, decrement. Of course, you need to think about what happens if you are at the edge of the grid.

Comment: that was very stupid on my side, sure it works way better with a 2D array

i'm sorry

edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
public class Location {
    private int x, y;
    private String name;

    // getters and setters here
}
```

Combined with

```
public class Game {
    private GameTile[][] field;

    // getters and setters here
}

public class GameTile {
     // some tile-specific information goes here
}
```

Thay way, you store the game-field specific information (in `GameTile`, if needed). If you don't need the `GameTile` class, you can just leave out the array in the `Game` class, and just store the maximum dimensions.

---

How does this answer your question:

- Going east would just be `x += 1`,
- west `x -= 1`,
- etc...